# What is the 10001st prime number? Why does my Java solution give the error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, error-handling, primes

So this is my Java code for Project Euler #7(description of problem commented out in code):

```
   // By listing the first six prime numbers: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, and 13, we can see that the 6th prime is 13.
   // What is the 10001st prime number?
    boolean isPrime = true;
    long [] primes = new long[10001];
    int j = 0;
    while (j < 10001){
        for (long i = 2; i < 1000000000000000L; i++) {
            for (long k = i; k < i / 2; k++) {
                if (i % k == 0) {
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isPrime) {
                primes[j] = i;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(primes[10000]);
```

When I run this code, this is what I get as a result :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10001

```
*at vasila.mir.Main.main(Main.java from InputFileObject:22)*
```

When I press on the **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** error it gives me this "Find why 'j' could be 10001". When I press on that, this is what I get :

**primes[j] = i; in Main.main(String[]) (filter: 10001)**

I don't understand what that means, and it doesn't really help me.
What could be the problem with my code?

Comment: Additionally to the answer of Eran: the prime test loop doesn't work. `for (long k = i; k < i / 2; k++) {}` will never execute, since `k` is initialized with `i` and therefore the condition `k < i / 2` is always false

Comment: Java arrays start at 0 and go to length - 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `for (long i = 2; i < 1000000000000000L; i++)` finds more that 10001 primes, your outer loops condition is never checked in time to finish the program.

You should combine the loops

Change

```
while (j < 10001){
    for (long i = 2; i < 1000000000000000L; i++) {
```

to

```
for (long i = 2; i < 1000000000000000L && j < 10001; i++) {
```

You should also reset `isPrime` to `true` at the start of the outer for loop.
And in the inner loop, `k` should start at `2`, not `i`.

The following works:

```
long [] primes = new long[10001];
int j = 0;
for (long i = 2; i < 1000000000000000L && j < 10001; i++) {
    boolean isPrime = true;
    for (long k = 2; k <= i / 2; k++) {
        if (i % k == 0) {
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isPrime) {
        primes[j] = i;
        j++;
    }

}
System.out.println(primes[10000]);
```

Output:

```
104743
```

Comment: This did work, but it actually gives the 10000th prime number instead of the 10001st. I caught this error in my own code, and a few changes I would make to your solution are j<=10001 rather than j < 10000 and change the array to hold 10002 elements, as well as print out primes[10001]. Thank you so much for the helpful solution!

Comment: I also realized me error with k = i; as i % k would always return true and the bool isPrime would always be false, but somehow I deleted my own comment

Comment: @Vasila_M actually that's not the error in my code. primes[10000] should contain the 10001'th prime (since primes[0] contains the 1st prime). The error is that the inner loop considers 4 to be prime. The only fix required is `for (long k = 2; k <= i / 2; k++)`.